# Bootstrap delete item in database

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, yii

In my website I have two accounts where one is for administrator and one is for user. Admin have the ability to edit, create and delete. All of this function that I implemented are working fine but now when I open my user in another browser and I execute a delete function from admin in another browser it is not auto updated to the user site. I need to manually refresh my page in my user site to see the current records.

**What is the method to auto update/auto refresh the user page whenever there is a modification made from the administrator?**

Below is my code in the controller where i execute the delete function. Please let me know where i can adjust my code to auto refresh the content in user site.

**This is the access rules**

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('view','user'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update', 'admin','delete'),
            'expression' => 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()'
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

**This is the delete function**

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    if(Yii::app()->request->isPostRequest)
    {
        // we only allow deletion via POST request
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

    }
    else
        throw new CHttpException(400,'Invalid request. Please do not repeat this request again.');
}
```

Comment: Please check [this][1] post, it is advised for php, just apply as MVC style.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629642/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-when-a-database-is-updated

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are familiar with using ajax in javascript. if not please have a look at [this.](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/388/ajax-form-submiting-in-yii/)

1.Now you can set a timer in your JavaScript which gets called sat after every 10 seconds. In this javascript code write the ajax call.

```
var myVar=setInterval(function(){myTimer()},1000);

function myTimer()
{
//ajax call here
}
```

.2 Make a controller which this ajax function will call. Say checkflag

```
public function actionCheckFlag()
{
//check timestamp here, calculate timer difference between current time and the time of change in Db.You have to make timestamp with the each Db table.
}
```

Set some criteria in above action lets say the difference between current time and change time of Db table is say 1 minute then return some flag. Based on this flag refresh update some specific element. lets say update gridView. Or you can reload the whole page like

```
location.reload();
```