# Refresh/update shopping cart when I change quantity - PhP

Tags: javascript, php, e-commerce, cart, product-quantity

I'm currently making a webshop with php. I want to know how I can refresh the page when the user changes the quantity of a product, so it can recalculate the total price.

[image]

Is there an easy way to do this with php? Or with another language like javascript. Examples or projects with the same topic are welcome :)

Thank you

Comment: Using javaScript you can do it easily .

Comment: You can send data to and from the browser to and from the server with [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). Take a look at it and get back when you have some code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629878/2210140 This can help you.

Comment: An easy way is to add another button "Update quantity" or such, that would save the new quantity and reload the page.

Comment: @BikashP, Do you have an example?

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen that's what I found on google too, I see AJAX everywhere to do such things. I don't have skills with AJAX, thats why I'm first searching solutions in php or javascript. but I'll check it out, Thank you :D

Comment: @Zero Thats what I thought first, but I don't want a button where the user has to click after every modification.