# moving circles to a new coordinate in d3.js

Tags: javascript, php, d3.js

I'm new to programming. I've been messing around trying to create something like an indoor map with tags on it. My question is how can I refresh the tags on the map whenever the database is updated without reloading the page?

Thank you for your kind answer
Here is Some of the code:

```
<div id ="main" class="container">
    <div class = "row">
        <div id="map" class = "pull-left map"></div>
                    <?php
                        $tag_locations = array();

                        $sql = "SELECT activity_record.tag_id, employee.first_name, activity_record.x_coor, activity_record.y_coor, tag.tag_color, activity_record.timestamp FROM activity_record, tag, employee WHERE activity_record.tag_id = tag.tag_id && tag.employee_id = employee.employee_id && activity_record.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(t2.timestamp) FROM activity_record t2 WHERE t2.tag_id = activity_record.tag_id)";

                        $tag_result = $conn->query($sql);
                             while($tag_record =mysqli_fetch_assoc($tag_result)){

                            $tag_locations[] = $tag_record;

                        }

                    ?>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        var data = <?php echo json_encode($tag_locations); ?>; 

                        var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 700)
                        .attr("height", 450);
                        var g = svg.append("image")
                                .attr("xlink:href", "resources/images/map3.png")
                                .attr("width", 700)
                                .attr("height", 450)
                                .attr("x", 0)
                                .attr("y", 0);



                        var circle = svg.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(data)

                        .enter().append("circle")
                        .attr("cx", function(d) {return d.x_coor;})
                        .attr("cy", function(d) {return d.y_coor;})
                        .attr("r", 11)
                        .style("fill", function(d) {return d.tag_color;});


                        $('svg circle').tipsy({ 
                            gravity: 'w', 
                            html: true, 
                            title: function() {
                                var d = this.__data__;
                                return '<span style="color :' + d.tag_color + '">' + d.first_name + '</span>'; 
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

Comment: Learn about AJAX so you can dynamically load your data as JSON and rebuild your map.

Comment: @BonHam [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4629878/3040381) answer is similar to a solution you want...although you don't necessarily have to use jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You would need to poll the back-end (PHP?) in regular intervals checking for a database change. This would be done via an AJAX request:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Even though AJAX is named after Asynchronous Javascript and XML, it is quite common to use it with JSON.