# DIsplay real time SQL data on web form

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a small project but currently stuck in the process and your help would be much appreciated.

I am trying to display data from one of my SQL tables onto web form (asp), which will effectively be updating as long as data is being entered into the table.

I have managed to get it to work by using the META Tag which refreshes the page every 2 seconds, but I know this is not an ideal way of doing it. It was advised to me to update the web form only from server to client when there is a new inserted value, however I do not know how to approach this.

Please see below to my current code.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Label1.Text = "Cache Refresh:" & _
        Date.Now.ToLongTimeString

    SqlDependency.Start(GetConnectionSTring())

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(GetConnectionSTring())
        Using Command As New SqlCommand(GetSQL(), connection)
            Dim Dependency As New SqlCacheDependency(Command)

            Dim NumberOfMinutes As Integer = 3
            Dim Expires As Date = _
                DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(NumberOfMinutes)

            Response.Cache.SetExpires(Expires)
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Public)
            Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(True)

            Response.AddCacheDependency(Dependency)

            connection.Open()

            GridView1.DataSource = Command.ExecuteReader()
            GridView1.DataBind()

        End Using
    End Using

End Sub

Private Function GetConnectionSTring() As String

    Return "Data Source=xxxxxxxxx; Initial Catalog=Test; User ID=xxx; Password= xxx;"

End Function

Private Function GetSQL() As String

    Return "SELECT ProductCode, ProductName, Cost FROM dbo.OrderTempTable"

End Function
```

Thank you for your input.

Comment: You might want to search for these keywords: ajax, websocket, updatepanel. These are all different ways of doing it.

Comment: if you want to update from server to client (i.e. when the server triggers the message) then you'd have to use websockets (e.g. for .NET SignalR is the commonly used tool). The other methods (meta refresh, ajax) are client-to-server and thus you just have to poll randomly until it happens to update.

Answer (score -3):

I think you have to check the DB every certain time.

[THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629642/how-can-i-refresh-a-page-when-a-database-is-updated) is for PHP but the idea is the same.

[HERE](http://blog.codebusters.pl/en/auto-refresh-content-after-changes-in-database-ajax/) another example.

Comment: please don't post link-only answers, it will just get flagged and removed as being low-quality. Instead, include some relevant content within your own answer. Links can change or die after a while. By all means provide a link as the source of the answer or to point to more in-depth discussion.